# Which Geeta shlok says thus?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, identification-request, gita

Which Geeta verse means

> "The world isn't bad because of bad people's deed. It's bad because inaction of good people."

The better version could be: In troubled times, those who have ability to do something also has responsibility to do something.

Comment: There is no such direct shlok in Geeta, although you can infer this from the conversation.

Comment: You can edit your question to ask how Geeta implies this meaning. It would be answerable. For this question the answer is - "No such direct verse from Geeta say so."

Comment: I think this is some random forwarded message. No gita verse explicitly says this.

Answer (score 4):

No Bhagvad Gita verse says so. These are just homemade verses disguised as Gita.

Similar: [Which verse of the Bhagavad Gita says "If you don't fight for what you want, don't cry for what you lost?"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10216/1049)