# Where in the Rāmāyaṇa does this quote appear? Who said this?

Tags: ramayana, identification-request

Tell me where it is being said & by whom?

> The fragrance of the flower is never borne against the breeze;but the fragrance of human virtues diffuses itself everywhere.

[image: Image with the quote]

Comment: I never came across that line. It should be something like this: `Rama wanted to take comfort in the breeze, at least. But that breeze itself is troubling him, because it is carrying the fragrance of the pollen of lotuses, which is like the fragrance of Seeta's breath` which has somewhat same meaning.

Comment: Its mentioned in Kishkinda kandh, chapter 1 verse 72.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava you can answer

Comment: nope I'm still not sure as the quote actually points out a human character. So in my view either guru vasisht is teaching this or SriRam himself telling this to someone.

Comment: This quote is from a book published in 1882 called [Pebbles Pearls and Gems of the Orient](https://archive.org/stream/pebblespearlsan01millgoog#page/n84/mode/2up). It ascribes the quote to Ramayana but I've not been able to find any such quote...perhaps the author merely applied his imagination to twist the original verse (which we do not know) or perhaps it was picked from a folktale version of the Ramayana?

Answer (score 5):

Possibly **Nowhere**.

To me, this seems to be from some creative mind, who wanted to let the fragrance of his/her own thoughts diffuse over the internet if not air. My analysis is based on Google search for this quote, partially & fully.

To gauge the authenticity of a quote, we need to check the source of that quote. If we see such quote in Facebook, Whatsapp, Twitter, other social media-s, then the genuineness of the quote will be equivalent to that site, which is least. In social media anyone can upload anything without backup -- whether true or false.

You may find your quote as an image in [this link](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/380061656035246380/?lp=true).
For example, the same link also contains following image. As expected, it's not present in Gita either (see the spelling of "Bhagavad"). There are few other quotes from Ramayana as well in that link, which also can be non-existent.

[image]

As already discussed in following post, there are many homemade quotes flowing in social media on the names of Gita, Ramayana, Mahabharata, Veda, Purana etc. They ought of be ignored.
[Which verse of the Bhagavad Gita says "If you don't fight for what you want, don't cry for what you lost?"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10216/1049)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, But Geeta fraud quotes doesn't imply This is also fraud quote. :-)

Comment: @Rohit., the Gita's false quote is just an example taken from a site, which has so many such false quotes. The Ramayana quote mentioned in your Qn could also have been sourced from that site. That site may not be fraud, but people might have just uploaded the quotes on their own accord. If you have the source of your quote, then you may check its authenticity. If the source is not authentic (e.g. FB, Whatsapp, Twitter), then the quote contained in it is least likely to be authentic.